# Request for info on the space of commuting matrices preserving a flag.

Tags: linear-algebra, flags, hilbert-schemes, nilpotent-matrices, commuting-variety

Fix a flag of subspaces V<sub>1</sub> in V<sub>2</sub> in V<sub>3</sub>, etc. all in C<sup>n</sup>.

Consider the space of pairs of commuting linear transformations A and B such that:
A preserves the flag (i.e. A(V<sub>i</sub>) is in V<sub>i</sub>), and
B *strictly* preserves the flag (i.e. B(V<sub>i</sub>) is in V<sub>i-1</sub>).

Does anyone know anything about this space?  Is there any literature on it?  Is it smooth?

Just as an example: if the flag is trivial, B=0 and A can be anything.  So that's smooth.

Answer (score 1):

for the case where n = 2 and the complete flag the variety in question is isomorphic to A^2 x Spec C[x,y]/(xy).  so the space is not nec. smooth.